# Replace string of text in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a large list of Data in Google Sheets that requires reformatting. I was hopeful that there may be a formula I could use to avoid manual entry.

Example
Current text String in cell A1 - 367/23
Would like text to appear in Cell B1 as 23-367

Need to flip numbers before and after the "/" and replace the "/" with a "-"

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"/(.*)") &"-"& REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.*)/")
```